# Generating random Unicode between certain range

Tags: python, random, unicode

I am trying to generate random Unicode characters with two starting number+letter combination..

I have tried the following below but I am getting an error.

```
def rand_unicode():
    b = ['03','20']
    l = ''.join([random.choice('ABCDEF0123456789') for x in xrange(2)])
    return unicode(u'\u'+random.choice(b)+l,'utf8')
```

The error I am getting:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: end of string in escape sequence
```

I use Python 2.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, uh, that's not how.

```
return unichr(random.choice((0x300, 0x2000)) + random.randint(0, 0xff))
```

Comment: How would I go about making it between the ranges U+0300-U+036F and U+20D0-U+20FF?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use two `range()` calls to generate the ranges, add them together to fuse them, and then `random.choice()` to pick one.

Comment: @mikeyy: `unichr(random.choice(range(0x300, 0x370) + range(0x20d0, 0x2100)))`